# how to get calendar value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, calendar

I want the value from **html script** and I am trying to print it on my screen using print but its not working am using `python 2.7` with selenium for automation testing how could I get calendar value thanks.[working on this website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B29Vs.jpg)

code

```
import unittest
import time
import gettext
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class xyz(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
     
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        driver=self.driver
        


    def test_xy_org(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.veenaworld.com/")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        find=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtSearch']")
        find.send_keys("pune")
        find.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        find2=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@onblur]") 
        find2.send_keys("pune")
        find2.send_keys(Keys.RETUR)
        self.driver.get("https://www.veenaworld.com/Package/Detail?pCode=RJZB(IP)&cCode=2")
        enquiry=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Enquiry']").click()
        name=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtEnName']")
        name.send_keys("prajkta")
        phn=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtEnContact']")
        phn.send_keys("4569874556")
        city=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ddlEnCountry']").click()
        city1=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('ddlEnCountry')/option[6]").click()
        email=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtEnEmail']")
        email.send_keys("fgdshk@gmail.com")
        destination=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('ddlEnDest')/optgroup[2]/option[4]").click()
        travel=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('optTour')/option[2]").click()
        mounth=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('ddlEnTMonth')/option[7]").click()
        year=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('ddlEnTYear')/option[3]").click()
        more=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('txtEnMoreDetail')")
        more.send_keys("djgfjhgdh genghruu jjdhgjh gerhjhrj")
        option=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('EmailMe1')").click()
        submit=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('frmEnquiry')/div[1]/div[12]/input[1]").click()
        time.sleep(5)

        self.driver.get("https://www.veenaworld.com/")
        flights=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#hm_tab2']").click()
        from1=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='fromcityAc']")
        from1.send_keys("pune")
        to=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='tocityAc']")
        to.send_keys("mumbai")
        travellers = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//div[@id='Travellersection']//div[@class='dd_poup']//p[@class='dd_poplink']//span[@class='dd_poplink_span']").click()
        option = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ddlAdultInt']").click()
        adult = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ddlAdultInt']//option[@vlaue='2']").click()
        option1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ddlAdultInt']//option[@vlaue='2']").click()
        self.ab()


    def ab(self):
        date=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtFlightDepartureDate']").click()
        month=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]") 
        to_month_string = month.get_attribute('value')
        print 'to_month_string'
        date='Feb 2018'
        if to_month_string==date:
         print "month selected"
        else: 
         for x in to_month_string:
               click1=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html//div[@class='datepick-popup']//a[3]").click()
            
       

if __name__=="__main__":

     unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='example17_dir'))
```

Please see

## 2nd function def ab(self):

## date= am trying to click on calendar

and after that am giving **xpath** of month that locate the calendar month and that what i want to print as a output

Comment: It might be helpful to post some of the html that you are processing. Also describe the problem you are experiencing at the moment.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

following code is for calender which has wheel type view & from first wheel we can select date by rotating that wheel. same for selecting month & year.At the end there is confirm button to save the date.

```
    public void verifyClickOnDate() {
                IOSElement Date = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpaths.DATE));
                Date.click();
                driver.findElementByXPath(("//XCUIElementTypeDatePicker/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypePickerWheel[1]")).sendKeys("28");
                driver.findElementByXPath(("//XCUIElementTypeDatePicker/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypePickerWheel[2]")).sendKeys("December");       
                driver.findElementByXPath(("//XCUIElementTypeDatePicker/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypePickerWheel[3]")).sendKeys("2018");
                IOSElement confirmDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpaths.CONFIRM_DATE_BUTTON));
                confirmDate.click();
                String Date = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpaths.DATE)).getText();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take text value from given tag.

Try below line of code

```
month=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]") 
        to_month_string = month.text;
```